# unlist inside a dataframe and insert it as new row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I have a dataframe with two columns: `value` and `article_topics` as follow:

```
 str(myData)
Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ value         : num  288 253 967 36769 2769 ...
 $ article_topics:List of 10
  ..$ : logi NA
  ..$ : logi NA
  ..$ : chr  "art and entertainment" "music" "style and fashion" "clothing" ...
  ..$ : chr  "hobbies and interests" "guitar" "art and entertainment" "music" ...
  ..$ : logi NA
  ..$ : chr  "pets" "large animals" "sports" "fishing" ...
  ..$ : chr "health and fitness"
  ..$ : chr  "style and fashion" "clothing" "shirts"
  ..$ : logi NA
  ..$ : logi NA
```

I would like to `unlist` `article_topics` such as I get one observation per `article_topics`.

If I take an easier example it would basically mean transforming:

```
value        article_topics
10       “Hello” , “This is an example”
```

into this:

```
value           article_topics
10                “Hello”
10                “This is an example”
```

Here is the dataset:

```
structure(list(value = c(288, 253, 967, 36769, 2769, 541, 17, 
889, 532, 2621), article_topics = list(NA, NA, c("art and entertainment", 
"music", "style and fashion", "clothing", "lingerie", "movies and tv", 
"movies"), c("hobbies and interests", "guitar", "art and entertainment", 
"music", "musical instruments", "guitars", "technology and computing", 
"consumer electronics", "telephones", "mobile phones", "smart phones"
), NA, c("pets", "large animals", "sports", "fishing", "freshwater fishing"
), "health and fitness", c("style and fashion", "clothing", "shirts"
), NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("value", "article_topics"))
```

I have been trying to use `melt` from `reshape2` and `gather` from `tidyr`. However it does not work for this kind of structure or I could not figure it out.

I came into a partial solution:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(ll, 'article_topics',',', 'long')
   value             article_topics
 1:   288                         NA
 2:   253                         NA
 3:   967  c("art and entertainment"
 4:   967                    "music"
 5:   967        "style and fashion"
 6:   967                 "clothing"
 7:   967                 "lingerie"
 8:   967            "movies and tv"
 9:   967                  "movies")
10: 36769  c("hobbies and interests"
11: 36769                   "guitar"
12: 36769    "art and entertainment"
13: 36769                    "music"
14: 36769      "musical instruments"
15: 36769                  "guitars"
16: 36769 "technology and computing"
17: 36769     "consumer electronics"
18: 36769               "telephones"
19: 36769            "mobile phones"
20: 36769            "smart phones")
21:  2769                         NA
22:   541                   c("pets"
23:   541            "large animals"
24:   541                   "sports"
25:   541                  "fishing"
26:   541      "freshwater fishing")
27:    17         health and fitness
28:   889      c("style and fashion"
29:   889                 "clothing"
30:   889                  "shirts")
31:   532                         NA
32:  2621                         NA
```

The next step would be to use something like `stringr` to replace `c(` and `)`.
However this is not really a nice way to do it in my opinion.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: I would suggest trying `listCol_l(unclass(df), "article_topics")[]` from my "splitstackshape" package instead of `cSplit`...

Comment: This does work like a charm!
Thank you.
I wonder if you can come up with the tidyr answer as well.
Please edit your answer adding this and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm on a system that has some old packages right now and I don't have rights to update them, so I'll try some more with the tidyr approach a little later. Glad to hear that `listCol_l` worked for you.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Actually doing this:
`myData %>% mutate(article_topics=ifelse(is.na(article_topics),as.character(article_topics),article_topics)) %>%unnest(article_topics)`
Works as well. You can edit your solution if you want for it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: A complete solution would be like that:
`myData %>% mutate(article_topics=ifelse(is.na(article_topics),as.character(article_topics),article_topics)) %>%unnest(article_topics) %>% mutate(article_topics=ifelse(article_topics=="NA",NA,article_topics))`
However, in term of performance it is really poor :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unnest`. Try:

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(myData, article_topics)
```

Example output:

```
> head(unnest(df, article_topics))
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

  value        article_topics
1   288                    NA
2   253                    NA
3   967 art and entertainment
4   967                 music
5   967     style and fashion
6   967              clothing
```

---

Alternatively, you can try `listCol_l` from my "splitstackshape" package. It's not compatible with `tbl_df`s, though, so you need to `unclass` it first.

Try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_l(unclass(df), "article_topics")[]
```

Comment: It actually does not work:
`unnest(t,article_topics)
Error: incompatible type at index 3 : character, was collecting : logical`
However thank you for the tip. didn't know this function! :)
I believe that is because I have logical struct in my article_topics

Comment: @zipp, can you create an example that demonstrates the error?

Comment: The error is reproducible frome the example data (I'm using tidyr 0.3.1). You could try for example `DD %>% mutate(article_topics = as.character(article_topics)) %>% unnest(article_topics)`

Comment: @Ananda Mahto 
The structure that I gave give me the error.
`> library(tidyr)
> unnest(ll,article_topics)
Error: incompatible type at index 3 : character, was collecting : logical`

Comment: @docendodiscimus, I'm on a system running an older version of "tidyr". I'll try on my other system.

Comment: @docendodiscimus your example sadly cast the list like this: `c("art and entertainment", "music", "style and fashion", "clothing", "lingerie", "movies and tv", "movies")`
using dplyr_0.4.3 and  tidyr_0.3.1